# Is it possible to create a VM from the disk(s) of a failed physical machine?

Tags: virtualization

I have an old machine which has failed, looks to be a motherboard fault, but as far as I know the disks, a pair of 120 gig SATA drives using software RAID, are OK.  So the machine can't be booted but its OS and data are believed to be intact on the disks.

Is there any simple way to create a VM, in VMware or XenServer, from just the disks?  I am assuming both disks will be identical copies of each other so either can be used as a source, and I can easily mount one or both to a different machine.  I have access to multiple hypervisors that a virtual version can run on.  Were the machine running I'd just use the VMware Standalone Converter but that obviously isn't possible with a dead box.

Comment: Create new one virtual machine for your purposes. Mount virtual hard disk for this virtual machine on you OS (linux preferred) and connect one of the HDD from your old server. Create correct filesystem on the mounted virtual hard disk and use `rsync` to copy OS from HDD to virtual hard drive. Unmount virtual drive, then boot your virtual machine via boot ISO and repair boot manager. You could use `dd` too to make a copy of data. With linux system it can be easy, with windows it can be difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Without working hardware, plug the drives in somewhere else. Possibly some other physical box with free bays, enclosures, or docks.

Create a new guest. Image both drives into virtual disks, their status is not certain and recovery will be cleaner with both present.

Regarding tools, [vCenter Converter](https://docs.vmware.com/en/vCenter-Converter-Standalone/index.html) outputs VMware, and [libguestfs virt-p2v](http://libguestfs.org/virt-p2v.1.html) outputs Linux KVM. Either of these guides you in the creation of the guest. For the do it yourself method, you could boot the new guest with a rescue DVD, then image each disk from the remote by piping dd through ssh.

In general, p2v source of not the original server should be fine. As long as you pick which disks to image. And tweak the OS configuration for any hardware differences, such as renamed network interfaces. Worst case, replace hardware and delay the p2v migration.